# RxJs: Filter array with inner observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of routes, which I'm trying to filter on depending if the service says the user has permission. I've tried various combination & transformative operators with no success `mergeMap, concatMap, concatAll, mergeAll`. The problem is that `hasRoutePermission` returns an observable that returns a boolean from the endpoint. Thanks in advance.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8teg8k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
const exampleRoutes = [{
  model: 'ExampleModel'
}, {
  model: 'ExampleModel'
}, {
  model: 'ExampleModel'
}, {
  model: 'ExampleModel'
}];

filterRoutes(routes): Observable <[]> {
  const hasRoutePermission = (route: IRouteData): Observable <boolean> =>
    this.examplePermissionService.hasRoutePermission(route);

  return of(items)
  .pipe(
    filter(item => hasRoutePermission(item))// Problem is here
  )
}
```

I'm using an async pipe to subscribe to the filtered list in the template.

Comment: Hard to follow here, `exampleRoutes` isn't used. Can you make a stackblitz?

Comment: Your usage of items and item make me think that you haven't yet understood how filter works and that you're confusing the rxjs operator filter with the Array filter method. If the observable emits arrays, then filter operates on the entire array, not individual items of the array.

Comment: @Phix updated with stackblitz as close as possible to replicate.

Comment: @IngoBürk please help me understand :)

Comment: @alphapilgrim I suggest you read up on observables a bit. Two immediate issues come to mind with your example. 1) You're assigning the result of this.filterRoutes to this.routeItems - the returned type of this method is an Observable<[]>, and notably not an array. 2) You seem to be trying to handle this purely synchronously and that's not what Observables do - rather, they execute lazily and only when subscribed to (as in the answer below). In the subscribe method, you'll set routeItems to the result, not as an assignment from the function as you've got now.

Comment: @alphapilgrim Not intended to be snarky - purely noting how your sample uses the concept and trying to encourage you to learn more about them (as it's a rather common mistake by new users to RxJS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you receive boolean value inside Observable and now need to use one of "flattening" operators (like `mergeMap`, `concatMap`, etc) to get back primitive value:

```js
const { of, from } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { mergeMap, filter, map, toArray } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

function hasRoutePermission(id) {
  return of(id % 2 === 0); // mock api logic
}

function filterRoutes(items) {
  return from(items).pipe(
    mergeMap(item =>
      hasRoutePermission(item).pipe(
        filter(permission => permission),
        map(() => item)
      )
    ),
    toArray()
  );
}

const filtered$ = filterRoutes([0,1,2,3,4,5]);
filtered$.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```