# Best way to filter rxjs Observable array with an Observable filter function

Tags: rxjs, observable

**Consider the following sample:**

I have a non completing rxjs Observable providing me with an array of numbers (e.g. `of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`) and a custom filter function that returns an Observable boolean (also non completing) for each number (signifying whether the number should be included in the result or not).

**My question:** What is the best combination of operators to apply this filter?

**Note:** A solution using `toArray` (like described in [RxJs: Filter array with inner observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693858/rxjs-filter-array-with-inner-observable#63694457)) won't work for me:  The observables returned by my filter function never complete and for obvious reasons `toArray` can only work with streams that do.

What I came up with so far is this monster using the `scan` operator: https://stackblitz.com/edit/from-and-back-to-array?devtoolsheight=133&file=index.ts

I believe it works, but I can't help thinking that there must be an easier way to accomplish this.  Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific what are you trying to do? I don't know what's a non completing filter function returning Observable or what the stackblitz code suppsoed  to do.

Comment: Yeah I'll try to rephrase my question a bit, but it *is* a complicated setting. By "non completing Observable" I mean an Observable that never calls `complete()` internally. (For example `interval(100)` creates such an Observable for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work.

```ts
const filtered$ = remoteSource$.pipe(
  // if new source values come in, switch to those and discard the current values
  switchMap(nums => {
    // an array of observables each emitting a number if it passes the filter or else undefined
    const checkedNumbers = nums.map(num => numFilter$(num).pipe(
      map(isValid => isValid ? num : undefined)
    ));
    // combine those observables
    return combineLatest(checkedNumbers);
  }),
  // filter out undefined values, i.e. numbers that didn't pass the filter above
  map(checkedNumers => checkedNumers.filter(num => num !== undefined)),
);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/from-and-back-to-array-6slvvf?file=index.ts

Comment: Wow - that was fast! Thanks a lot. I hadn't though about `switchMap` in this setting.

Comment: I found just one small issue but that actually wasn't something I explained in my question: I also need the filter to emit when there are no values in the Observable array (`remoteSource$`). I just had to add a `if (nums.length === 0) { return of([]); }` at the top of the `switchMap`.

Comment: prefer not define something as `undefined`. I think `null` is better (please correct me if I'm wrong). And then filter by simply doing `!!num` instead of the `num !== undefined` (or just use the lodash `compact`). Using the array.filter can still think the type contains `undefined` but `compact` is typed correctly.